# htaccess redicect to www exclude subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

i have the following rule to redirect non www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but now i want a subdomain assets.company.com το be excluded but nothing seems to work for me

i have try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^assets\. [NC] [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and its not working

Pleas help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|assets)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- Make sure to keep this as first rule.
- Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid caching issues.